# How to find MIN with criteria in R

Tags: r

```css
year event athlete time
2000 100m Ato Boldon 9.95
2000 100m Brian Lewis 10.02
2000 100m Coby Miller 9.98
2000 100m Francis Obikwelu 9.97
2000 100m Jon Drummond 9.96
2000 100m Maurice Greene 9.86
2000 100m Michael Marsh 10.01
2000 100m Obadele Thompson 9.97
2000 100m Tony McCall 10.06
2001 100m Ato Boldon 9.88
2001 100m Aziz Zakari 10.04
2001 100m Bernard Williams 9.96
2001 100m Dwain Chambers 10
2001 100m Josh Norman 10.17
2001 100m Kim Collins 10.04
2001 100m Leonard Scott 10.05
2001 100m Mark Lewis-Francis 10.12
2001 100m Maurice Greene 9.9
2002 100m Bernard Williams 9.99
2002 100m Chris Williams 10.13
2002 100m Francis Obikwelu 10.01
2002 100m J.J. Johnson 9.95
2002 100m Kim Collins 9.98
2002 100m Marc Burns 10.18
2002 100m Mark Lewis-Francis 10.04
2002 100m Maurice Greene 9.89
2002 100m Shingo Suetsugu 10.05
2002 100m Taiwo Ajibade 10.18
2003 100m Bernard Williams 10.04
2003 100m Deji Aliu 9.95
2003 100m Dwain Chambers 10.06
2003 100m Hrist<f3>foros Ho<ed>dis 10.16
2003 100m J.J. Johnson 10.05
2003 100m John Capel 9.97
2003 100m Justin Gatlin 9.97
2003 100m Kim Collins 9.99
2003 100m Maurice Greene 9.94
2004 100m Asafa Powell 9.87
2004 100m Ato Boldon 10.09
2004 100m Christie van Wyk 10.09
2004 100m Darrel Brown 10.11
2004 100m Francis Obikwelu 10.02
2004 100m Justin Gatlin 9.92
2004 100m Maurice Greene 9.91
2004 100m Mickey Grimes 10.12
2004 100m Shawn Crawford 9.88
2005 100m Asafa Powell 9.77
2005 100m Aziz Zakari 9.99
2005 100m Dwight Thomas 10
2005 100m Francis Obikwelu 10.04
2005 100m Justin Gatlin 9.89
2005 100m Leonard Scott 9.94
2005 100m Marc Burns 9.96
2005 100m Maurice Greene 10.01
2005 100m Shawn Crawford 9.99
```

I am working with a dataset in R that has four columns: Year, Event, Athlete, and Score. Each row is an observation of an athlete's score within a given event and year.

What I would like to do is to create a new column that would display each athlete's all time best score, with best being represented as their lowest score.

In excel I would just create a minifs formula that would check if the given year's score was smaller than previous years scores and if it was that would become the athlete's all time best score and if it was not then it would print out whatever their previous best score was.

I apologize if this has been asked and answered before, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You describe a very clear process/logic, but we'll need some data in order to properly help you.

Comment: One solution could look like   `library(dplyr);  data %>% group_by(athlete, event) %>% filter(score == min(score)) %>% ungroup()`.

Comment: The [`ave`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/ave) function could be used here.

Comment: @AntoniosK thank you for the response, is the above snippet useful?

Comment: You should also provide your desired outcome. However, I've just posted a solution, which I think will help you. Have a look and let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: I actually solved my question! Using the following code `library(dplyr); data %>% group_by(event, athlete) %>% mutate(all_time = cummin(score))` Thank you again to everyone for their help, this is an awesome community!

Answer (score 1):

```
# example data
df = read.table(text = "
year    event   athlete time
2000    100m    AtoBoldon   9.95
2001    100m    AtoBoldon   10.02
2000    100m    CobyMiller  9.98
2003    100m    AtoBoldon   9.97
2001    100m    CobyMiller  9.96
2003    100m    CobyMiller  9.86
", header=T)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(athlete, event) %>%  # for each event and ethlete
  mutate(best_time = min(time), # get minimum time
         year_best_time = year[time == best_time]) %>%  # get year of minimum time
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#    year event athlete     time best_time year_best_time
#   <int> <fct> <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>          <int>
# 1  2000 100m  AtoBoldon   9.95      9.95           2000
# 2  2001 100m  AtoBoldon  10.0       9.95           2000
# 3  2000 100m  CobyMiller  9.98      9.86           2003
# 4  2003 100m  AtoBoldon   9.97      9.95           2000
# 5  2001 100m  CobyMiller  9.96      9.86           2003
# 6  2003 100m  CobyMiller  9.86      9.86           2003
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, thank you so much for your time! My desired outcome column would be the that athlete's best time up to that point. So in the example above take the athlete CobyMiller for example in row 3 I would like my desired column to say his best time was 9.98 because that is the only observation we have for him. In line 5 his new best time would be 9.96 because we have two data points now, and in line 6 his best time would be 9.86. Does that make sense? Essentially I want to know what the athletes best time is up to that year. Thank you so much again for your time!

Comment: Glad to see you've solved the issue! `library(dplyr); data %>% group_by(event, athlete) %>% mutate(all_time = cummin(score))` is the right way to do it. Make sure your dataset is always properly ordered when you run this code and if you want to use your output in the future it would be good to use `... %>% ungroup()` in the end so the grouping doesn't create any problems in the future.

Comment: that is a great point, I will make sure to add order and ungroup! thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

The Excel MINIFS function returns the smallest numeric value that meets one or more criteria in a range of values. Here are examples of simple R replications:

```
# 1. Libraries
library(dplyr)

# 2. Data set
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2000, 2000, 2000),
  athlete = c("Ato Boldon", "Brian Lewis", "Coby Miller"),
  event = c("100m", "100m", "200m"),
  score = c(9.95, 10.02, 9.98))

# 3. Replicate Excel 'MINIFS' function

# 3.1. One solution
df %>% 
  group_by(event) %>% 
  filter(score == min(score)) %>%
  ungroup()

# 3.2. Another solution
df %>% 
  group_by(event) %>% 
  mutate(min_score = ifelse(event == "200m", min(score), score)) %>%
  ungroup()

# 3.3. By 'athlete' for all time best score with 'year'
df_athlete_all_time <- df %>% 
  group_by(athlete) %>% 
  mutate(min_score_all_time = min(score)) %>% 
  subset(select = c("athlete", "min_score_all_time")) %>% 
  unique() %>% ungroup()

# 2.4. Merge with original data
df_merge <- left_join(df, df_athlete_all_time, by = c("athlete"))

# 2.5. What 'year' best score took place
df_merge %>% 
  filter(score == min_score_all_time)

 # 2.6. Compare it to all the athlete's previous years scores and print out the smaller of the two
 # Homework :)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrii! but what I am trying to create is a new column within the data frame that lists each athlete's all time best score, not just what the best score was within an event. So I would need the code to know what year the the score took place in for each athlete and compare it to all the athlete's previous years scores and print out the smaller of the two. Does that make sense?

Comment: You should use a not new column with the list. It's better to split it into separate jobs. I added 2 pieces of code where you should go ... please don't forget to assess my time

Comment: Definitely appreciate your time! I apologize, as I am new to posting questions so I hope I am following the correct etiquette. Your code allows me to see each athlete's minimum score which is fantastic but what I am looking for (and I am sorry if this was not clearer) is the athletes best time but considering the year as well. So if an athlete competes in years 2000, 2001, and 2003 and we are looking at his 2003 row, I want the code to check his times from 2000, 2001 and 2003 and tell me what his minimum time was. Does that make sense?

Comment: if you appreciate my time you can spend 1sec to click on upvote

Comment: Just did, but looks like I'm too new for it to be displayed. Thanks again!